# Gaussian Exponential Sum Approximation

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, approximation, exponential-family

Let $x_j,\ j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ be independent standard Gaussian random variables and $a_j,\ j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ be constants. What would a function $f$ and a standard Gaussian random variable $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is a good approximation of the probability distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{a_ix_i}$?

For small $a_i$'s, I can take the first order Taylor expansion of $e^x$ and $f(x_0)=n+a_0x_0$ where $a_0^2 = \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$. Are there any other better approximations?

Comment: The answer usually is "nothing," unless the $a_j$ are very special.  Your expression is a sum of independent lognormal distributions.  If any of the $a_i$ is even of modest size and positive, then even for very large $n$ that distribution won't be approximated well by any Gaussian.  Rather than constraining or simplifying your question so severely that only bad answers are possible, why not tell us what the underlying problem is that has motivated your post?  What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: A common trick in these sums (whose name escapes me at the moment) is to factor out some term $e^{Mx}$, where M could be the maximum or minimum, typically, or anything else that makes your life convenient. However, its doubtful how much that will help in your case.

Comment: @whuber and jwimberley: I will state the original motivating question later. What about $f(x_0)=e^{a_0x_0}$? Will the sum of independent lognormal distributions be approximated well by a lognormal distribution? Or will a normal distribution constructed by moment matching be good? I think it could be justified by central limit theorem for large $n$?

Comment: There is a "philosophy" in geostatistics called "conservation of lognormality."  It is the belief that in many cases small linear combinations of lognormal variables can be considered still to have (approximately) lognormal distributions.  The CLT doesn't necessarily apply: it is merely asymptotic, and with many lognormal distributions the asymptotics don't kick in until there are thousands of terms (or more), depending on how large the $a_i$ are.

Comment: @whuber: To find the parameters $b_0$ and $a_0$ in the lognormal distribution $f(x_0)=b_0e^{a_0x_0}$ we can match the first two moments. Is there a  good and fast/convenient approximation under some constraint (like smallness of $a_i$'s)? I suppose you can expand the exponential to the first order and then use the square root of the sum squared of $a_i$'s. But I do not know how accurate this is going to be.